# Api request that return virtualHosts list name or ip

Tags: web-server, apache2, url, html, whitelist

Is there a way for send a request to apache web server and it be returned list of all virtualHosts, name or ip address? Can be done it with some api?

I Know that executing **apache2ctl -S** I get info on virtualhost

```
VirtualHost configuration:

*:80 is a NameVirtualHost
        default server **first.example.com** (/etc/httpd/conf.d/first.example.com.conf:1)
 
Main DocumentRoot: "**/var/www/html**"
```

*I don't have access to apache2ctl program on pc server.*

My goal is obtaining a small list of links from private network o home network. Urls can get from html files but files are in var/www/. Url can get try the combinations of words and test with http HEAD request address.

I want list ip address writings in virtualHosts config file for downloading main html page of first.example.com.

with regard

Comment: I suggest you to edit a post and move your "comment" inside of it. It really belongs to a question.

Comment: Of course I can share html files with file server as samba and scan it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache has no such API.

You can use a script on the server to run apache2ctl.